# Index was outside the bounds of the array VB

Tags: vb.net

This is my code and when I run it appears index was outside the bounds of the array in line b = Asc(y(j + m)). I have tried Try and Catch and it didn't work out.

```
Public Function SMITH(x, y, SX, SY)

    Dim a, b, j As Integer
    result = 0
    m = x.Length
    n = y.Length

    preBmBc(x)
    preQsBc(x)

    j = 0
    While (j <= (n - m))
        If (SX = SY.ToString.Substring(j, m)) Then
            result = 1
        End If
        a = Asc(y(j + (m - 1)))
        b = Asc(y(j + m))
        j = j + Math.Max(bmBc(a), qsBc(b))
    End While

    Return result

End Function
```

Comment: How about trying not letting the index go outside the bounds of the array instead? Use the debugger, and step through the code. What does that show you? We can't do that for you, because we don't know what you're passing as `x, y, SX, SY` to your SMITH function.

Comment: What are the values of y, j and m? I suspect something is not being set correctly. Debugging should help?

Comment: You will always have an exception at y(j+m).  j+m at the last iteration is equal to n.  Therefore y(n) would be beyond the array length.  I think you need the a to be Asc(y(j + (m-2)) and b= Asc(y(j+m).  You might need to start at j=1.

Comment: thankyou guys, i have solved it with adding "y += \0" in my code to add the index of y.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making m = "m-1" for b also? You really need to step through the code using breakpoints and the debugger to figure out when the program throws the OutOfRangeException.